# About Query statement in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I use this code for paging in mysql (working with Struts 2 + Hibernate):

```
Query query=getSession().createQuery("from GovOffice");
query.setFirstResult(0);
query.setMaxResult(100);
List<GovOffice> list=query.list();
```

This will return list of GovOffice which is started from the first record, display 100 records per page.

Suppose i have 100,000 records, is this query "from GovOffice" get all 100,000 records first?
 By setFirstResult and setMaxReSult it will limit from 100,000 to 100 records.If this is true that means paging must be useless.

If not is there any way to prove that query will not get data from DB until we call `query.list()`.

Comment: You could print out the hql that hibernate creates and look to see what it does. But I believe it limits it on the db side and only returns your 100 results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Query`'s `setFirstResult` and `setMaxResult` use the underlying possibilities of the databases.

In the case of MySQL, it's [limit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/select.html).

So, no, it doesn't fetch all records and yes it's efficient.

The proof in the source code ([org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/3.3.1.GA/org/hibernate/dialect/MySQLDialect.java?av=f)):

```
238 public String getLimitString(String sql, boolean hasOffset) {
239     return new StringBuffer( sql.length()+20 )
240         .append(sql)
241         .append( hasOffset ? " limit ?, ?" : " limit ?")
242         .toString();
243 }
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the documentation makes it pretty clear that only the max results will be retrieved from the database.

[setMaxResults(int)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setMaxResults%28int%29)

Seems to me to be the equiv of

```
SELECT * FROM GovOffice LIMIT 0, 100;
```

Comment: The question is about Hibernate and this is not relevant to the question. Hibernate may use JPQL/Hibernate (HQL) queries (which is special). This would not work. `SELECT*` would not work in Hibernate.

Comment: The OP stated this was for MySQL and in the case of MySQL usage, my statement is correct that his code reflects the SQL statement I wrote above.

Comment: The code is clearly relevant to Hibernate and the question is also tagged with Hibernate.

Comment: "Seems to me to be the equiv of". Not sure why you think I am indicating MySQL SQL should be used instead of HQL.

Comment: I'm not the opponent of your answer and sorry for too much involvement but this `createQuery()` method can't run such SQL. It's a kind of native SQL. You must write something like this `createQuery("from GovOffice")`. It's first executed by HQL (stands for Hibernate Query Language) processor and then it is converted to its corresponding native SQL. You can't write something like this `createQuery("SELECT * FROM GovOffice LIMIT 0, 100")`.

Comment: Yes, I completely understand that. What I am saying is my query is the equivalent of the OP's code. Not that anyone should use it to create a query in Hibernate. The OP seems to be unsure of what his code translates to in MySQL so the query is just a clarification.

Comment: @Lion: tencent is perfectly correct on this one: the HQL "from GovOffice" on a Query object with a maxResult of 100 results in a SQL Query similar to "SELECT * FROM GovOffice LIMIT 0, 100;".